# Question about equilibrium points of linear multi-step methods

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

What are the conditions on the coefficients of a linear multistep method that guarantee an equilibrium point of the ODE will always be an equilibrium point of the linear multistep method, and vice versa?

Comment: That is called stability. You want $A(\alpha)$ stability, of which a first condition is zero stability. See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3321082/115115 where I collected most of the definitions from Hairer-Wanner II.

Comment: Cool, thats hepful. But, for a generic linear multistep method, is there any way to tell if the equilibrium points of the ODE and multistep method are equal (by just looking at the coefficients)?

Comment: Yes, if a method reaches an equilibrium, this means that the left side of the multistep method gives zero and the right side is a multiple of the function value at the equilibrium, thus also an equilibrium of the ODE. What stability prevents is the spontaneous development of oscillations around the equilibrium due to floating point noise accumulation.